Understanding the case when $P_3$ is normal and $P_2 \cong \mathbb Z _2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ is not normal to classify a group of order $12$
I am studying the classification of groups, when the Klein 4-group arises as a subgroup. The first example comes from Artin about groups of order $12$. He uses proof by cases, and the only case that confuses me occurs when the Sylow 3-group $P_3$ is normal, but the Sylow 2-group $P_2$ is isomorphic to the Klein 4-group and not normal.
My understanding of Artin's proof: $P_3$ is of prime order, so it must be cylic. Let $P_3 = \langle y \rangle$ s.t. $H$ will act transitively by conjugation on the set $\{y, y^2\}$. By the orbit stabilizer theorem,
$$|\text{Stab}(y)|=\frac{|H|}{|\{y, y^2\}|}=\frac{|\mathbb Z _2 \times \mathbb Z _2|}{|\{y, y^2\}|}=2$$
implying $\text{Stab}(y)=\{1,z\}$ for some $z \in H$. There exists $x \in H$ s.t. $x \not\in \text{Stab}(y)$. $zyz^{-1} = y$ shows $zy=yz$, and $xyx^{-1} \ne y$ requires $xyx^{-1} = y^2$ so that $y \ne 1$ still holds. As $H \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z _2$ is abelian,
$$G = \langle x,y,z : x^2=y^3=z^2=1,yz=zy, xz=zx, xy=y^2 x \rangle$$
Artin concludes with the ad hoc approach that $D_6$ is the only group of order $12$ that had not been classified by this point, necessitating $G \cong D_6$.
Question: Is it possible to study this group by examining the homomorphisms $\phi: \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \to \text{Aut}(P_3) \cong \mathbb Z_2$? $\phi$ will be determined based on where it sends the generators of $\mathbb Z _ 2 \times \mathbb Z _ 2$, encouraging us to adopt the following presentation.
$$\mathbb Z _ 2 \times \mathbb Z _ 2 = \langle x, z : x^2 = z^2 = 1, xz = zx \rangle$$
Case 1 $\phi(x) = \phi(z) = 1$: $\phi(xz) = \phi(x) + \phi(z) = 1 + 1 = 0$, so $\text{ker}(\phi) = \{1, xz\} $.
Case 2 $\phi(x) = 1$, $\phi(z) = 0$: $\text{ker}(\phi) = \{1, z\}$
The last case is similar, so we see that every non-trivial homomorphism has a kernel of two elements and maps the other two to $1 \in \mathbb Z_2$.
We might as well select case $2$, because we can freely relabel the elements of $\mathbb Z _2 \times \mathbb Z _2$. Let us also take $f : \mathbb Z_2 \to \mathbb Z _ 3 ^ \times \cong \text{Aut}(P_3)$ by $f(n)=2^{n}$. $f(0)=2^{0}=1$ and $f(1)=2^{1}=2$. We see that $f(0)$ is the identity map $i \mapsto i^1$, while $f(1)$ is the map $i \mapsto i^2$.
$$\phi(x)[y] = xyx^{-1} = f(1)[y]=y^2$$
$$\phi(z)[y] = zyz^{-1} = f(0)[y]=y$$
We recover the same relations $xy = y^2x$ and $zy = yz$.
Is this argument correct? How can we show that this presentation yields the dihedral group without the Todd-Coxeter algorithm, a multiplication, or exhausting all the cases?

I didn't really understand your question. The dihedral group of Artin is defined as the symmetry group of a regular n-gon. However, on page 165 there is a proposition 3.6 in which it is proved that the dihedral group can be defined in terms of generating and three relations. Finally, at the very end of the proof of the theorem on groups of order 12, in the case you mentioned, he simply gives two generating and three necessary relations. It's only seven lines. Could you please clarify what exactly your question is?

@kabenyuk Sorry, I was wondering primarily if the argument by counting homomorphisms was correct. As a little aside, I just wanted to know how to easily see that my presentation did actually yield the dihedral group.

That's understandable. However, you first write, ‘the case that confuses me occurs.’ As for your argument, it’s still unclear how you are reasoning: 1) your count of homomorphisms seems incorrect, and 2) it’s unclear how you construct a group using those homomorphisms.
